# Getting TypeInitializationException in VS2012, But Not 2010

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio

I am getting a `TypeInitializationException` when I try to debug my application in Visual Studio 2012, but I am able to run the application in Visual Studio 2010 without error.

I recently moved a bunch of stuff around (including my project and several references) in order to get it into a version control system.  I had to relink several items so that everything would link correctly when checked out on a different system.

Our development environment is mixed (VS2010 & VS2012).  Running out of VS2010 produced no errors.  But when I ran the Debug in VS2012 I received the `TypeInitializationException` exception.

The project in the *original* directory (where it resided before moving for version control purposes) still runs fine in both VS2010 and VS2012.

There is a flag or a parameter or something that got a little messed up somewhere, but I'm not sure where.  Does anyone have any ideas on what I can do to get this to work in VS2012 as well?

(please let me know what, if any, code or config information to include here)

**InnerException:**

> The type initializer for 'System.Windows.Navigation.BaseUriHelper' threw an exception.

**(Second) InnerException:**

> The type initializer for 'MS.Internal.TraceDependencyProperty' threw an exception.

Comment: What does the Inner Exception say?

Comment: Question updated with InnerExpcetion.

Comment: There's another inner exception. If you walk down the "InnerException" of your exception to the first one that is not a "The type initializer..threw an exception", what is it?

Comment: Question updated again... also answered the question, as this sparked further searches and a result.

Comment: Crazy stuff, love to know the real reason.  We'll have to wait for a better stack trace.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Comments on the original question sparked further searches, which ultimately yielded a solution.

Doing a search for "The type initializer for 'System.Windows.Navigation.BaseUriHelper' threw an exception." I found the following StackOverflow question: [WPF Application fails on startup with TypeInitializationException](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58425/wpf-application-fails-on-startup-with-typeinitializationexception)

Similar to that question I had added a `<startup> </startup>` block to my "app.config" file.  Where this tag block was placed made the difference:

**Causes Error in VS2012:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
    <startup useLegacyV2RuntimeActivationPolicy="true">
        <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.0,Profile=Client" />
    </startup>
    <configSections>
       ...
    </configSections>
    <applicationSettings>
       ...
    </applicationSettings>
</configuration>
```

**Everything works fine:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
    <configSections>
       ...
    </configSections>
    <applicationSettings>
       ...
    </applicationSettings>
    <startup useLegacyV2RuntimeActivationPolicy="true">
        <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.0,Profile=Client" />
    </startup>
</configuration>
```

Moving the tag block to the bottom did the trick!

Comment: OMG, thanks for the informative message Microsoft - that is 4 hours of my life I will never get back.

Comment: It appears this is happening with VS2015 as well.  Worked perfectly.

Comment: Encounter same issue in VS2013... the order of xml node matters --- is it a bug of Visual Studio?

Comment: It is the order of the <configSections> that matters - not <startup>; refer to http://stackoverflow.com/a/36923982/2093880